# Could not enter date manually using jqxDateTimeInput

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqxwidgets

We are using jqxWidgets as a part of UI in our project.

To display the date we are **jqxDateTimeInput** widget.
The problem here is we could not manually input the date without using calendar icon. But in the demo shown in jqxwidget website in the link below the date can be edited manually.

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdatetimeinput/index.htm#demos/jqxdatetimeinput/defaultfunctionality.htm

Does anyone what should be done to make the date field to be edited manually?
Is there any license restriction on this?
We are yet to get the license and now we are using trial version.

**- JS extract:**

```
$("#fromDate").jqxDateTimeInput({
        width : 200,
        height : 25,
        formatString : "dd/MMM/yyyy",
        theme: theme
    });
```

Comment: how do you initialize your widget? js code pls

Comment: $("#fromDate").jqxDateTimeInput({
  width : 200,
  height : 25,
  formatString : "dd/MMM/yyyy",
  theme: theme
 });

Comment: is there any js error in your console?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, adding globalize.js helped

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here. I spend a lot of hours to fix it, but I got it! I had 2 calls of jQuery: one in the main file, with 1.9.1 version and another in my grid file, with 1.10.2 version. After removing the call of 1.9.1 version, I solved the problem. Check your jQuery calls and try again.

Comment: mine got fixed by adding globalize.js